# Unable to find KickoffActivity Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using this site to build a chatapp, just for learning purposes. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

Unfortunately I always end up getting an error. I found this question [how to solve Unable to find explicit activity in firebase AuthUi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476866/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-in-firebase-authui?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but none of the answers solved my issue.

This is the error message:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.user.chatatwork/com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

My `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.myapp.user.chatatwork">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:value"
    >


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is my gradle(app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**EDIT**

This is the `KickoffActivity` class in Firebase:

```
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
public class KickoffActivity extends HelperActivityBase {
    private static final String TAG = "KickoffActivity";
    private static final String IS_WAITING_FOR_PLAY_SERVICES = "is_waiting_for_play_services";
    private static final int RC_PLAY_SERVICES = 1;

    private boolean mIsWaitingForPlayServices = false;

    public static Intent createIntent(Context context, FlowParameters flowParams) {
        return ActivityHelper.createBaseIntent(context, KickoffActivity.class, flowParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        if (savedInstance == null || savedInstance.getBoolean(IS_WAITING_FOR_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
            if (isOffline()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No network connection");
                finish(ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK,
                       IdpResponse.getErrorCodeIntent(ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK));
                return;
            }

            boolean isPlayServicesAvailable = PlayServicesHelper.makePlayServicesAvailable(
                    this,
                    RC_PLAY_SERVICES,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            finish(ResultCodes.CANCELED,
                                   IdpResponse.getErrorCodeIntent(
                                           ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR));
                        }
                    });

            if (isPlayServicesAvailable) {
                SignInDelegate.delegate(this, mActivityHelper.getFlowParams());
            } else {
                mIsWaitingForPlayServices = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // It doesn't matter what we put here, we just don't want outState to be empty
        outState.putBoolean(ExtraConstants.HAS_EXISTING_INSTANCE, true);
        outState.putBoolean(IS_WAITING_FOR_PLAY_SERVICES, mIsWaitingForPlayServices);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_PLAY_SERVICES) {
            if (resultCode == ResultCodes.OK) {
                SignInDelegate.delegate(this, mActivityHelper.getFlowParams());
            } else {
                finish(ResultCodes.CANCELED,
                       IdpResponse.getErrorCodeIntent(ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR));
            }
        } else {
            SignInDelegate delegate = SignInDelegate.getInstance(this);
            if (delegate != null) delegate.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is an active or soon-to-be-active network connection.
     *
     * @return true if there is no network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isOffline() {
        ConnectivityManager manager =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return !(manager != null
                && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
```

to the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

Comment: did you sync ,clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes, i did all of these. nothing worked. it says "manifest merger failed" and in the logs, there is the error which i mentioned above.

Comment: the `kickoffActivity` is a class in the firebase ui auth package, can be found here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/KickoffActivity.java. Whenever you add a dependency in the gradle file of your project the activities of that library will be added to a manifest file.(Explained more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) that is why adding the library in the project manifest wont work, the best bet is to update everything.

Comment: @Blnpwr what do you want to use in firebaseui? (auth or database?) The activity is in the firebaseui auth, if you only want to use database then use this `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'` instead of `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'` and you won't get that error

Comment: What do you mean by "update everything". In your answer you have the newest version of firebase. Is there anything more to update? I don't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168174/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-blnpwr).

Answer (score 1):

The following error:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.user.chatatwork/com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Tells you exactly what the problem is. You are using an activity, named `KickoffActivity` that is not declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. To solve this, please add the following line of code, right after the `</activity>` tag.

```
<activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity"/>
```

Updating the Firebase and Firebase-UI dependencies to the last version, as Peter mentioned in his answer, it is very good practice.

Comment: Please share an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your `KickoffActivity` class including the `package` name and the changed `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Please edit your question by adding the necessary code.

Comment: As far as I understood, this `KickoffActivity` should be added automatically because I am using Firebase, there are a lot of other classes that are implemented automatically when using Firebase. I don't have any KickoffActivity class.

Comment: If you are using Firebase it doesn't mean that the `KickoffActivity` activity will be added automatically in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Yes you have, either this error would not have appeared. Check your `com.firebase.ui.auth` pakage for a KickoffActivity.java file. Can you share its content and the changed `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: I edited the question with the KickoffActivity class, Alex.

Comment: Because `class KickoffActivity extends HelperActivityBase` it means that the `KickoffActivity` class is an activity. In order to make it work, you need to declare this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Have you added this line `<activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity"/>` inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file? Also can you conform that `"com.firebase.ui.auth"` is the right package for the `KickoffActivity.java` file?

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Cheers @Blnpwr!